# Export the mysql data (data in other language or having some special character ) as CSV file in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

In My app,
I am fetching the content from mysql table and export it as a csv.
The table contains other language characters and special characters like

```
 *♣ Joy ♣, 观弈路人, Qυееп ☺̐ '*̣, معين الاسلام,அரவிந்*
```

but it is not  format as it is in CSV instead it is displayed as

```
 * ë¶€ì‚°ë¹„ì—”ë‚ ë ˆ, QÏ…ÐµÐµÐ¿ â˜ºÌ '*Ì£, Ù…Ø¹ÙŠÙ† Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù*…....
```

is it possible to display the characters like the one in DB?

Comment: depends on encoding. Remove the charset utf-8 encoding specifier and browse the page. Or find the right charste

Comment: I didnt specify any charset as UTF8 ..

Comment: I specified the HMTL entities in meta tag for utf-8 encode like 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> but still it not showing correct format of that language

Comment: also check the DB Character set

Comment: while fetching and displaying in browser, the content is displaying correctly but while export it as csv am not getting the same format like in DB after export in csv.

Comment: we need to add any header to get the same format in CSV??

Comment: db Character set is in latin1

Answer (score 0):

As I've worked a lot with "non-english" characters, several things are required for proper display and storage of those characters.

In no particular order (as I don't know what charset is best suited for Persian, I'll use UTF-8, if it's different, you just use the one you need):

Tell your browser what charset you are using, either by setting the proper header from PHP header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); or set the meta tag in your html like so:

In the database avoid mixing different collations and charsets in the columns/tables. I always set the database, the tables and the columns to utf8_general_ci which for my needs work all the time (languages like English, German, Serbian, Hungarian...).

As Jan said, read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html You'll most likely need to execute query something like SET NAMES utf8 right after connecting to the database.

All this should ensure the proper displaying of unicode characters. However, there is one more thing that can override all this - the web server. Apache (don't know about the other servers) has a AddDefaultCharset directive. On most setups this is left as Off, but I did came across setups where the default charset was set to latin1, thus overriding all my charset settings. If this is set, it is set in the httpd.conf (or similar configuration file). If you have access to it, I recommend setting it to Off. If you don't, then you can override the global value with .htaccess placed in your webroot, with something like: AddDefaultCharset utf-8